# Will making API calls like this lead to performance issues?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to make an API call when a screen is focused but I'm not sure if doing it looks like this is the best way to do it. I tried use effect with a subscriber and clean up function but I got an error

```
function ResolveTrackScreen(props) {
    const { resolveTrack } = useContext(TransactionContext)

    props.isFocused ? resolveTrack() : null

    return null
}

ResolveTrackScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        headerShown: false
    }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(ResolveTrackScreen)
```